# LINUX awk loop through several lines of a txt file

Tags: linux, loops, awk

I need to loop through several rows of a text file and redirect to another text file.

I managed to do the following:

```
for i in $(seq 1 24)
awk 'NR==1 {print $4 $5 $6}'  3dfwhmx.txt > values.txt
values='cat*values.txt'
3dClust -fwhmxyz ${values}
done
```

However this only address the `first row`, `4,5,6th column`. I would need to use the `i` index in order to address the `1st, 2nd, 3rd etc row`. 
I do need to create a vector of values for each iteration of i.

I tried several things eg;

```
awk 'NR=='$i'  {print $4 $5 $6}'  3dfwhmx.txt > values.txt
```

but it does not work. I would really appreciate any feedback on this!

Comment: Please edit your question so that it complies with http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

do you need to loop through it and call awk for each line?

Why not just

```
awk '{print $4}'  3dfwhmx.txt > values.txt
```

or change your quotes to allow the shell substitution

```
awk "NR==$i {print $4}"  3dfwhmx.txt > values.txt
```

Comment: Hi Ian, yes, I need to loop it and call each line because I then need to redirect those specific values to another piece of program. Do you know how to do ?

Comment: Not what OP asked for

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks, this works but only to some extent. I address row through i but not able to select just the 4th column but it rather selects the entire row....

Comment: Hi JID, do you have any solution ?

Comment: awk "NR==10 {print $4}" gives you 10th line's 4th word

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop around `awk`.

```
awk 'NR<=24{print $4}'  3dfwhmx.txt > values.txt
```

will get you the first 24 lines as your logic with loop does.

---

With the updated question, you don't need a temporary file either.

```
for i in $(seq 1 24); do
   values=$(awk -v i=$i 'NR==i {print $4 $5 $6}'  3dfwhmx.txt)
   3dClust -fwhmxyz ${values}
done
```

Depending on how `3dClust` works, you might be able to simple redirect `awk's output to its stdin using a pipe.

Comment: This is not what I need.. is there a solution?

Comment: @Matilde Updated answer for your modified question.

Comment: I need the temporary file... how can I do  considering the example I have given?

Comment: hmm..then use temp file: `for i in $(seq 1 24); do awk -v i=$i 'NR==i {print $4 $5 $6}'  3dfwhmx.txt > values.txt;   values='cat*values.txt'; 3dClust -fwhmxyz ${values}; done`
done